# What URL should be used to update a property of all members of a collection

Tags: rest, http

I am wrapping a legacy CLI interface into a web service/interface (using JAX-RS) and using REST style as far as possible.

The service manages CRUD of a collection of entities, plus an additional, `[de]activate` action pair, which change the `active` state and property of the entity.

For an individual entity, I have implemented activate/deactivate as:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
PUT /entities/{identifier}/active
DATA "true"|"false" 
RESPONSE 303 Location: /entity/{identifier}
```

However, the CLI also provides a useful operation to activate/deactivate all entities at once. This is effectively a global bulk update operation, as it (may) change the state of every entity in the collection.

I'm looking for suggestions on how best to express such global operations with URLs. I think there is no RESTful way to express them, but would be happy to be corrected. Are there any generally accepted or standard URL styles for this?

So far, for the global operations I am using this...

```
POST /entities/activate
POST /entities/deactivate
RESPONSE 204
```

... which I realize is not remotely RESTful, but at least has the benefit of being simple for a human client to understand and invoke. I'm looking for a better, and hopefully standard, approach to improve on this.

(I also considered using an `/entities/all` pseudo element, but decided it made things a bit more complicated on the server side with no benefit to clients.)

To recap:

- I have a resource called `entities` which represents a collection.
- Each member is an `entity`, identified by its `{identifier}`.
- Each entity has a number of properties including a boolean state property: `active`.
- Each entity can be activated and deactivated by invoking an operation.
- For individual entities, I am exposing that operation via a POST (or PUT) on `entities/{identifier}/active`.
- I think that much is reasonable.
- There is another operation, which I want to expose, which activates/deactivates all members of the collection.
- I am looking for a standard approach for expressing those two global operations, which change the state of all members of the collection, in a URL.

**Update**

Following Jon's suggestion, the activate/deactivate operation for all members of the entities collection shall become:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
PUT /entities/active
DATA "true"|"false" 
RESPONSE 204
```

Comment: This question seems to be about picking the best names for your URLs, so it seems like it would be mostly a matter of opinion, right?

Comment: @Maximillian Maybe so. But what I'm asking is whether there are any accepted or standard approaches to this general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What thing does `/entities/activate` represent. How does that thing differ from `/entities/deactivate`? If I'm doing something that changes them (`PUT`) or acts upon them (`POST`) why can I not use the same resource to activate as to deactivate?

This doesn't seem to make much sense. It seems like you are using URIs to identify operations.

However, `/entities/all` at least has the advantage of using a single identifier for a single resource (there's nothing "pseudo" about it, it's no less real than any of the other resources you made up).

`/entities/` would perhaps be better still. It's common, though certainly not required, and often useful (due to the ability to use common relative URI paths like `../`) to have the identifier of a step up in the path component identify the total of a set of related entities.

So, have `/entities/[some id]/` identify a given entity, and `PUT` something describing it as active or inactive to change that. Then have `/entities/` represent all of them, and `PUT` something representing the fact that they are all active or all inactive to set them all as such.

Comment: OK thanks. So using either an explicit "all" (pseudo-)member, or the collection resource name itself, as the target for operations which change the state of all members of the collection is what you suggest. Any evidence of this being a common approach?

Comment: Turn on directory browsing on a server. Go to the directory in a browser. Observe that the entity you receive describes a resource that is the collection of the contained resources. It's the same principle. It's a related principle that your `/entities/{identifier}/active` is a bad idea; what thing is `/entities/{identifier}/active`?

Comment: I have a resource called `entities` which represents a collection. Each member is an `entity`, identified by its `{identifier}`. Each entity has a boolean state property: `active`, and can be activated and deactivated by invoking an operation. I am exposing that operation via a POST (or PUT) on `entities/{identifier}/active`. I think that much is reasonable. My query was about the global operation (activate/deactivate all members of the collection).

Comment: Ah. I'd read it was suggesting that you had an opposing `/deactivate` and as such using URIs to identify operations instead of entities. To come back to the general, a "higher up" collection resource is a long-standing approach in HTTP, the only thing new is defining an entity to PUT that represents only a partial change. POSTing would be less controversial, perhaps.
There could be a good argument made for `/entities/are_all_active` that you could change to affect all of them similarly, which would have the advantage of giving you somewhere to GET to discover...

Comment: quickly whether all, some or none of them are active. PUT has a good advantage here either way as the operation is inherently idempotent in the sense HTTP uses the word; set them all active and set them all active again, and the effect is the same as if you'd done it just once. Set them all inactive and set them all inactive again and the effect is the same as if you'd done that just once, too.